# RequiredFieldValidator focusing the last radiobutton on a RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a radio button list in asp.net like

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblChoose" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
 RepeatLayout="Flow">
   <asp:ListItem Text="a" Value="a" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="b" Value="b" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvChoose" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="rblChoose" ErrorMessage="Choose registration option." 
ForeColor="red" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

When the `RequiredFieldValidator` shows the client message on error it is focusing the last `RadioButton` in the list. Why is it setting the focus on the last `RadioButton` in list. I would like to focus on the first `RadioButton` on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is happening as the generated HTML for the radio button will look similar to this. (Note the names \ ids will be changed to suit the application and heirchy).

```
<span id="MainContent_rblChoose"><span name="rblChoosea">
      <input id="MainContent_rblChoose_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblChoose" value="a">
      <label for="MainContent_rblChoose_0">a</label></span><span name="rblChooseb">
      <input id="MainContent_rblChoose_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblChoose" value="b">
      <label for="MainContent_rblChoose_1">b</label>
</span>
```

Now what is important is if you look at the `name` attribute. The names are the same as (for radiobuttons) so they correctly toggle between each other. This also sets which value is posted in the form event.

Now the default validator (if you dig through the MS javascript) eventually calls the following snippet.

```
var inputElements = ctrl.getElementsByTagName("input");
var lastInputElement  = inputElements[inputElements.length -1];
if (lastInputElement != null) {
        ctrl = lastInputElement;
}
```

If you review the code above you will notice that it actually gets the `lastInputElement` from the array of elements that match the element name and have a tag name of `input`. Therefore when the code executes to focus the `ctrl` it is focusing on the `last` element (as you see in your validation).

Now we know thats the default behavior, what we also need to know is how do we overcome this problem. Well thats where you will have to stay away from the `RequiredFieldValidator` control and write your own `CustomValidator` with a custom javascript function. Now this is quite simple and is only really valid for this case but can be done with a few lines of code.

First off you define your `CustomValidator` as such (example only).

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" 
                     ID="rfvChoose" 
                     ErrorMessage="Choose registration option."
                     EnableClientScript="true" 
                     ForeColor="Red" 
                     ClientValidationFunction="rfvChooseValidator" />
```

Noticing another property enabled of `ClientValidationFunction` this is a javascript function that will set the `IsValid` property to `true` \ `false` based on a set of conditions. The javascript is then quite easy to implement. Note in my example I have added special events to hide the validation message after a radio button is selected. I put alot of comments in the javascript so you can understand exactly what each stage does.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //function called when the rfvChoose validator is called
    function rfvChooseValidator(sender, args) {
        //set the object id for the radio button list
        var objID = '#<%= rblChoose.ClientID %>';

        //set the is valid flag by evaluating if any radio buttons in the radiobutton list are selected (using the psudo selector :checked)
        args.IsValid = $(objID + ' input[type="radio"]:checked').size() > 0;

        if (args.IsValid) {
            //if the validation is succesful remove the eventValidation custom click handler
            $(objID + ' input[type="radio"]').off('click.eventValidator');

            //hide the validation message
            $('#<%= rfvChoose.ClientID %>').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        else {
            //focus the first radiobutton in the list
            $(objID + ' input[type="radio"]:first').focus();

            //if the arguments are not valid set an event handler to trigger when any of the radio buttons are selected
            // the custom click event handler uses the .eventValidator namespace so we can on\off just the click handler for event validation
            // thus leaving all other click events enabled
            $(objID + ' input[type="radio"]').off('click.eventValidator')
                .on('click.eventValidator', function () {
                    //this simply recalls the validation function with a null sender and a blank object for the args 
                    // note the blank object is set using {} as opposed to null so in the callback we can set a property
                    // of this blank object. Passing null will cause an exception when trying to set a value.
                    rfvChooseValidator(null, {});
                });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Simply put the javascript function above will be executed every time the `CustomValidator` client validation events are raised.

Now I realize in the bounty statement that you only want to use a `RequiredFieldValidator` however this wont be possible if you would like to focus the first control

**UPDATE**

If you wish to change the `DisplayType` to `Dynamic` you must change the line

`$('#<%= rfvChoose.ClientID %>').css('visibility', 'hidden');`

TO

`$('#<%= rfvChoose.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');`

Or you can replace the code with the following snippet to auto-detect the display type and set the display\ visibility css accordingly.

```
//identify the display type
var displayType = $('#<%= rfvChoose.ClientID %>').data('val-display');
if (displayType === undefined || displayType == null || displayType == 'Static')
    displayType = { 'visibility': 'hidden' };
else
    displayType = { 'display': 'none' };

//hide the validation message
$('#<%= rfvChoose.ClientID %>').css(displayType);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response :) But is not there any way for doing it with require feild validator ?

Comment: As stated in the answer it is not possible. The JavaScript code embedded into the Microsoft Validation framework states to focus the last control matching the element. Therefore the only way would be to modify the JavaScript files from Microsoft and change your script references. I do not suggest this as it is a global change and may have (probably will) adverse affects. I would stick with the solution above as it's quite simple to implement and does not require changing the Microsoft core files.